# appent Json result to HTML table

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

```
{"status":1,"message":"Get type list","result":[{"event_id":"1","event_title":"Tesla motors, inc, first quarter 2014\r\nfinancila result Q&A conference call","event_date_time":"2014-05-24 18:59:59"},{"event_id":"2","event_title":"Tesla motors, inc, first quarter 2014\r\nfinancila result Q&A conference call","event_date_time":"2014-05-31 16:54:57"},{"event_id":"3","event_title":"Tesla motors, inc, first quarter 2014\r\nfinancila result Q&A conference call","event_date_time":"2014-05-20 21:52:57"},{"event_id":"4","event_title":"Tesla motors, inc, first quarter 2014\r\nfinancila result Q&A conference call\r\n\r\nTesla motors, inc, first quarter 2014\r\nfinancila result Q&A conference call","event_date_time":"2014-05-01 19:49:44"}]}

...//my ajax code
success:function(data){
alert(data.result[0].event_title);
}
```

I am getting this response result from ajax, and now I want to fill html table as per the result, I can successfully getting its any one row but failed to fill whole table.

How can I append this result to my html table ?

Comment: time to show thy code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
var tableString = "<table><tr><th>event_id</th><th>event_title</th><th>event_date_time</th></tr>";
for(var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++)
{
    tableString += "<tr>";
    tableString += "<td>" + data.result[i].event_id + "</td>";
    tableString += "<td>" + data.result[i].event_title + "</td>";
    tableString += "<td>" + data.result[i].event_date_time + "</td>";
    tableString += "</tr>";
}
tableString += "</table>";
$("#tableParentDivId").html(tableString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
for(var i=0;i<data.result;i++){
    $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>"+ data.result[i].event_id +"</td><td>"+ data.result[i].event_title +"</td><td>"+ data.result[i].event_date_time +"</td></tr>")
}
```